# What happened to SWIG?

Tags: python, swig

I'm working on a project that requires me to bind some C++ libraries to Python. Just today I found out the details about SWIG, and I got excited to use it, but the website:
http://www.swig.org/ seems to be down, and not just for me.  I don't know if I just came on a wrong day, or if the project has disappeared. Does anyone know what happened?

I was able to get a copy off of a GitHub mirror repo, and from Homebrew, but I'm not sure I should invest time in using it if the project has been dropped.

Thanks, I hope this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Good question.  You should check out SIP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP_%28software%29 ) and boost.python ( http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/GettingStarted ) also.  Personally I like to use Cython ( http://cython.org/ ) for such tasks, but depending on how object-y your C++ code is that might not work for you.

Comment: Maybe on the webapps stackexchange, but not here.

Comment: Thanks, @K.Brafford! I've currently been using Boost.Python but realized that I'd have to write some tools to parse my code and auto-generate some wrappers for me. SWIG seemed like it already did that. I haven't looked deeply into either Cython, or SIP yet, however. I know they use SIP for PyQt. Thanks again.

Comment: Doubt it's dead -- development was _very_ active as recent as [3 months ago](https://github.com/klickverbot/swig/commits/master). Also, when I project dies, usually it's website stays around for quite some time.

Comment: Also, it's a pretty popular project. If it died, someone else would almost certainly pick it up.

Comment: Okay, that's reassuring. Thanks for the answers.